# how to use removeAttr('disabled') in php by using 'class' instead of 'id'?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, web

this the code for table in php where column has a same id and each row has specific variable $i

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 <tr>
                 <td><input type='text' id='txt_id_".$i."' value=" . $row["Order ID"]. " disabled> </td> 
                 <td> <input type='text' id='txt_id_".$i."' value=" . $row["Request Date"]. " disabled></td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Tool"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td><button type='button' id='btn_update_".$i."' onclick='myFunction($i)'>update</button> </td>

  </tr>
i++}
```

the following code i executed when update button is pressed to remove the disabled attribute so I can change the value of the fields.

```
function myFunction(i){
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#txt_id_"+i).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#btn_update_"+i).attr('onclick','update('+i+')');
    });
```

}

but the problem arises when the press the update button only one the order id text field is revived not the date and tool field.

i cannot change id of all the textfields because their are ateleast 20 of them that makes my program unmanagable

Comment: Since `$i` doesn't seem to be changing, how can 3 fields have one same id? `id='txt_id_".$i."'`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky $i chanding all of this is in insde a loop. so for 1st row $i=1, 2nd row $i=2 and so on.

Comment: change ids of all textboxes, as all ids are same. thats why it is not working.

Comment: @Khushboo but i want to keep the id of attribute same because in originale website their are more then 20 fields i canot manage so many ids

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport for one row you have 4 td and you are giving same id for 4 of them

Comment: But javascript needs different ids to work. With same Ids, it will work for first element only.

Comment: @Khushboo ok. so is their any other way around it because i have to manage the data which i cannot do with 20 diffrent id.

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport you will need to use `class` rather than `id`.

Comment: @EternalHour don't want to be that guy, but could you give the code for a javascript, i don't know the lang.

Comment: Just change `id` to `class`, so it becomes `class='txt_id_".$i."'` and in javascript change `#` to `.`, so it becomes `$(".txt_id_"+i)`

Comment: @Lepanto thanks man.will try to do this way in sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                echo
                 "
                 <tr >

                 <td><input type='text' id='txt_orderid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value=" . $row["Order ID"]. " disabled> </td> 
                 <td> <input type='text' id='txt_dateid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value=" . $row["Request Date"]. " disabled></td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_toolid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Tool"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td><button type='button' id='btn_update_".$i."'  onclick='myFunction($i)'>update</button> </td>
                 <td><button type='button' id='btn_delete_".$i."'  onclick='DeleteFunction($i)'>delete</button> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_nameid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Name"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_emailid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Email"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_countid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Country Entered"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_countipid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Country IP"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_phoneid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Phone"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_planid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Plan"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_orderstatusid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Order Status"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='txt_actdateid_".$i."' class='txt_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Activation Date"]. " disabled> </td>
                 </tr>

                 ";
                $i++;
```

and to enable the the text

```
function myFunction(i){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".txt_id_"+i).removeAttr('disabled');

        $("#btn_update_"+i).attr('onclick','update('+i+')');
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Change ids of textboxes, like below :-

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 <tr>
                 <td><input type='text' id='order_id_".$i."' value=" . $row["Order ID"]. " disabled> </td> 
                 <td> <input type='text' id='request_id_".$i."' value=" . $row["Request Date"]. " disabled></td>
                 <td>  <input type='text' id='tool_id_".$i."' value="  . $row["Tool"]. " disabled> </td>
                 <td><button type='button' id='btn_update_".$i."' onclick='myFunction($i)'>update</button> </td>

  </tr>
i++}
```

And then, in javascript, use like below:-

```
function myFunction(i){
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#order_id_"+i).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#request_id_"+i).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#tool_id_"+i).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#btn_update_"+i).attr('onclick','update('+i+')');
    });
}
```

Comment: can we remove attr by class instead of ids

Comment: It is better to have jquery use a ID instead of a CLASS.

Comment: You can check here:- http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/......  very 1st point